# Check only 2 of 4 CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a quiz app, and every question has 4 answers, 2 of them are the correct ones. I use CheckBox for the answers. What I want is when the user clicks on 2 of the answers, then the remaining 2 to get unchecked. With other words, only 2 checked CheckBox at the time, and if the user has 2 checked and checks third one, then one of the two checked to get unchecked. I write a code that it is "half-working". When I check CheckBox starting from the first to the last is working, but clicking from the last to the first, nothing happens...

```
public void checkBoxClicked(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.checkBoxOne:
            case R.id.checkBoxTwo:
                case R.id.checkBoxThree:
                    case R.id.checkBoxFour:
            if (checkBoxOne.isChecked() && checkBoxTwo.isChecked()) {
                checkBoxThree.setEnabled(false);
                checkBoxFour.setEnabled(false);
            }else {
                checkBoxThree.setEnabled(true);
                checkBoxFour.setEnabled(true);
            }
             if (checkBoxOne.isChecked() && checkBoxThree.isChecked()) {
                checkBoxTwo.setEnabled(false);
                checkBoxFour.setEnabled(false);
            }else {
                 checkBoxTwo.setEnabled(true);
                 checkBoxFour.setEnabled(true);
             }
            if (checkBoxOne.isChecked() && checkBoxFour.isChecked()) {
                checkBoxTwo.setEnabled(false);
                checkBoxThree.setEnabled(false);
            }else {
                checkBoxTwo.setEnabled(true);
                checkBoxThree.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if (checkBoxTwo.isChecked() && checkBoxThree.isChecked()) {
                checkBoxOne.setEnabled(false);
                checkBoxFour.setEnabled(false);
            }else {
                checkBoxOne.setEnabled(true);
                checkBoxFour.setEnabled(true);
            }
             if (checkBoxTwo.isChecked() && checkBoxFour.isChecked()) {
                checkBoxOne.setEnabled(false);
                checkBoxThree.setEnabled(false);
            }else {
                 checkBoxOne.setEnabled(true);
                 checkBoxThree.setEnabled(true);
             }
             if (checkBoxThree.isChecked() && checkBoxFour.isChecked()) {
                checkBoxOne.setEnabled(false);
                checkBoxTwo.setEnabled(false);
            }else {
                 checkBoxOne.setEnabled(true);
                 checkBoxTwo.setEnabled(true);
             }
                        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try tracking the boxes that are checked using an array, (a queue would work perfect for this). When the user clicks on a checkbox, check if your array has two entries. If it has less than 2 entries, add the new checkbox to the list. If it has two entries, remove the first checkbox from the list, and add the new checkbox.

After your tracking code, you can simply uncheck ALL of the check boxes and only check those that you want.

Here I use an ArrayList for simplicity, but even a simple array would work. You could also use the id's instead of the actual views.

***Update Very Simple Working example.

Activity

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ArrayList<CheckBox> mChecks;
    private ArrayList<CheckBox> mSelectedChecks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

        mChecks = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
        mSelectedChecks = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

        //Load All checkboxes
        CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check1);
        CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check2);
        CheckBox check3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check3);
        CheckBox check4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check4);

        //Add to tracking list
        mChecks.add(check1);
        mChecks.add(check2);
        mChecks.add(check3);
        mChecks.add(check4);

        //Add Click listener
        for(CheckBox c : mChecks) {
            c.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        CheckBox c = (CheckBox)view;

        if(mSelectedChecks.contains(c)) {
            mSelectedChecks.remove(c);
        } else {
            if(mSelectedChecks.size() < 2) {
                mSelectedChecks.add(c);
            } else {
               mSelectedChecks.remove(0);
               mSelectedChecks.add(c);
            }
        }

        drawResults();
    }

    public void drawResults() {
        for(CheckBox c : mChecks) {
             c.setChecked(mSelectedChecks.contains(c));
        }
    }
}
```

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">


<CheckBox
    android:text="Check 1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/check1"/>

<CheckBox
    android:text="Check 2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/check2"/>

<CheckBox
    android:text="Check 3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/check3"/>

<CheckBox
    android:text="Check 4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/check4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am a complete beginner. I tried to copy/paste your code and that didn't work... I'm learning Java now and I only know the basic stuff. If it possible for you to post some code that I can use for my case I would appreciate.

Comment: I will try to post a complete example.

Comment: See my update, I have testing that this works. I have improved my original example, this should not flash when drawing.

Comment: Great! Thank you Jlange, your code works 100% and I was able to make my work done!